# Show that two intersecting circles can be mapped by a Möbius transformation to two lines which intersect at the origin...

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that two intersecting circles can be mapped by a Möbius transformation to two lines which intersect at the origin and which together are symmetric to the coordinate axes.

Having some trouble with this one. I think you want to send the two intersection points to 0 and infinity, but how do you ensure symmetry with the coordinate axes?

Comment: I think you asked something on this yesterday. You seemed unaware that one can compose any number of Mobius transformations, the resulting map is another Mobius transformation, and the coefficient matrix is just the product of the coefficient matrix. Begin by sending one of the circle intersections off to infinity.

Comment: suggest you work through, with actual numbers for coefficients: one circle around $1+2i$ of radius $\sqrt 5$  and one circle around $-1 + i$  of radius $\sqrt 2$

Comment: I'm aware of the fact you stated, and I already know I have to send one of the intersection points off to infinity. I have an example like the one you gave on the current set of problems I'm working through, but I still get stuck. I wouldn't ask this question if I hadn't already tried for hours.

Comment: the other intersection turned out to be $\frac{-6}{5}   + \frac{12}{5}  i $

Comment: The mapping would be 1/z. This is in reference to your comment that asked about taking the other intersection point (the origin) to infinity. Can't see that comment now for some reason.

Comment: I deleted it,  but this is fine. The other intersection goes somewhere; you may do a pure translation to move it from there back to the origin.  And, what sort of curves did the circular arcs map to?

Comment: The circles get mapped to extended lines through the origin. (after the translation)